# Пример использования mockito

Tags: java, jdbc, mockito, dao

Добрый вечер. почитал доки по mockito и решил использовать эти знания в своих юнит тестах. Вопрос в том правильно ли я понял смысл использования mockito. И Это нормально если я передаю в поведение одного mock объекта в другой?
Вот пример кода. Имеет ли он право на существование?

```
    Account account = new Account(1L, "Vova", "Borisov", "Vova@gmail.com");
    AbstractDaoFactory daoFactory = mock(AbstractDaoFactory.class);
    Connection connection = mock(Connection.class);
    AccountDao accountDao = mock(AccountDao.class);

    when(daoFactory.createConnection()).thenReturn(connection);
    when(daoFactory.getAccountDAO(connection)).thenReturn(accountDao);

    service = new ServiceImpl(daoFactory);
    service.createAccount(account);
    try {
        verify(accountDao).insert(account);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> И Это нормально если я передаю в поведение обмакнутого объекта другой обмакнутый объект?

Я думаю что нормально, правда не совсем понятно зачем вы делаете это:

> when(daoFactory.createConnection()).thenReturn(connection);
>       when(daoFactory.getAccountDAO(connection)).thenReturn(accountDao);

Но, возможно, это необходимо исходя из внутренней реализации ваших классов.

> Имеет ли он право на существование?

Мне кажется что вполне имеет право.
Единственное, чего, на мой взгляд, не должно быть в тесте - это проглатывания исключений:

```
   try {
        verify(accountDao).insert(account);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

В данном, конкретном примере, это не страшно, но вообще - очень и очень плохая практика. Если при выполнении теста вылетает ошибка, которую вы не ожидаете, то тест должен падать.
Для обработки кейсов, когда код должен кидать exception, есть свои подходы.

Comment: спасибо за замечание исправил :)